Using an onSubmit inside an enumerated ForEach doesn't get the right index
ForEach(Array(vm.numberOfResistors.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, resistor in
    UnitTextField(
        title: "Resistor \(index + 1)",
        value: $dummyVM.numberOfResistors[index].valueString,
        unit: $dummyVM.numberOfResistors[index].unit,
        focusField: $focusField,
        fieldType: "resistor \(index + 1)"
    ).onSubmit {
        if index <= vm.numberOfResistors.count {
            print(index)
            focusField = "resistor \(index + 1)"
        } else {
            print("2")
            focusField = nil
        }
    }.onChange(of: resistor) { oldValue, newValue in
        vm.numberOfResistors[index].value = Constants.convertToCoulomb(from: resistor.unit, value: Double(newValue.valueString) ?? 0)
    }
}.padding(.bottom)

I'm trying to use an onSubmit inside an enumerated for loop. However, for some reason the index is always 0. It does work perfectly fine one next onChange. Why is that?

Do not use indices with ForEach.  Refactor so that you have a proper array of objects to iterate.
